# div above navbar doesn't look as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Div above navbar is not in the top of body ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3ZNB.png)).

source:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
    <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
    <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
</div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color:#026;" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ՏԵՍԱԿՆԵՐ", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ՕԳՏԱԿԱՐ ՆՅՈՒԹԵՐ", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ԿԼԻՆԻԿԱՆԵՐ", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ԲԺԻՇԿՆԵՐ", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ՆՈՐՈՒԹՅՈՒՆՆԵՐ", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ԲԼՈԳ", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.affix {
        top: 0;[enter image description here][1]
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999 !important;
    }

        .affix + .container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
        }
```

I even tried using JavaScript but it doesn't help. I suppose Bootstrap doesn't let me to do that.

Comment: Depends on which version of Bootstrap. You're using Bootstrap 3 Navbar markup, so make sure you referencing Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Please, confirm the version of Bootstrap you are using. You can check a working example for **Bootstrap 3** here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&stacked=h

Comment: Bootstrap version: v3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` to the *.container-fluid* element's css?

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

I am unable to reacreate your problem. It should work, since it's pretty much the example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&stacked=h).

It might help if you provided a minimal working example of your code as a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or on something like [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/new) or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want your navbar to be at the bottom of the page, and you would like the background color to fill the whole item page (coded area).

To fix this...

- Add a wrapper div (call it .bg or something) directly inside the body tag
- Set the .bg class to width of 100 (w-100)
- Make sure the navbar is not in your .container class, but still inside the .bg wrapper class

Here below I made a simple bootstrap webpage with a background color, and a navbar at the bottom.
I did not use css for brevity, instead I used bootstrap included classes for background color, margins, etc...

If you want the whole webpage to be one color, set the html tag css to

background-color: #somecolor;

Good Luck!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bg bg-danger">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row w-100">
                    <h4>Bootstrap Afix Example</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="row w-100 mt-5">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-primary">button :)</button>
                </div>
                
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default sticky-top navbar-light mt-3 w-100 bg-secondary">
                    <ul class="nav mr-auto mt-1 mb-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="INSERT_YOUR_LINK" class="nav-item text-warning">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                            <a href="INSERT_YOUR_LINK" class="nav-item text-warning">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```